# Will I be able to benefit from free movement in Europe

Tags: europe, france, turkey, visa-free-entry

My mother is going to get her citizenship from France within a year or so. [In this website](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=457) it is stated that family members of EU nationals can have the right of free movement.

So will I be able to go to EU countries without doing anything? Just saying my mother holds French citizenship? By the way I am a citizen of Turkey, and I am above 18.

Answer (score 12):

This page has more details on your situation as a non-EU family member of an EU national: http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=463&langId=en

Most importantly it clarifies that you'll have the right to live, work and get educated *in the country your mother lives and works in*, not the entire EU. And it will probably require copious amounts of paperwork.

The page doesn't mention anything about traveling though, so you probably still need a visa to visit other EU countries.

Answer (score 5):

If you are under 21 or have a proof that your are dependent on your mother, you can [work or live](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/worker-pensioner/non-eu-family-members/spouses-children-parents_en.htm) in an EU country where your mother lives.

But if you keep living in a non-EU country, you will still need a visa to travel to an EU country, since you are Turkish citizen.

Answer (score 3):

Details are complex and partly off-topic for this site but understanding the logic behind EU law might help. Basically, you don't have any direct rights, only your mother does. That said, a person's right of free movement in the EU also entails e.g. traveling or moving to another EU country with their non-EU spouse or dependents.

But the idea is that precluding EU citizens to live with their children or spouse or care for their parents would hurt *the EU citizens' right* to move freely, not that the children, parents or spouse have any rights by themselves. Consequently, you will not generally gain any right to travel or work somewhere in the EU without your mother. In any case, you might still need a visa or residence permit where applicable, it's only that obtaining one should become easier.

Beside the useful links provided by Michael Borgwardt and Alp, the EU also has a [webpage on travel for members of an EU citizen's family](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/).

Answer (score 2):

You are an adult with non-EU citizenship. It is irrelevant if your mother is EU citizen or not, you will need visa to enter EU, and you will need certain permissions (differs in each EU country) to stay in EU. If your mother gets EU citizenship, it grants some rights to her, but not directly to you, because you are different person, you are not your mother. It will help, if your mother gets residence in EU, then you can get some benefits out of it, as a family member.